# How to assign window property value to control property on this form in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Suppose there is form MainWindow which has property string property Propery1. How to assign this property value to txtDisplay.Text property? Control txtDisplay is placed on form MainWindow .

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
      ...
        public bool Propery1
        {
            get { return this.txtDisplay.Text.Length > 0; }
        }
 ...
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Binary Calculator" Height="350" Width="625">
    ...
        <TextBox  Name="txtDisplay"  Style="{StaticResource MyTextBox}"  MaxLength="32" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="6" KeyDown="txtDisplay_KeyDown"/>
...
</Window>
```

Comment: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Propery1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" ...`. `Propery1` must be a dependency property for the text to be updated correctly.

Comment: Thanks, any link what Dependency Property means?:)

Comment: You're trying to put the string "True" in `txtDisplay` if `txtDisplay` has a string in it? I can show you the Dependency Property part, but the first problem is that this makes no sense at all. What are you trying to do with `Propery1`? `Propery1` is `bool`. Bool is not string. Once you explain what you're actually trying to do here, I can help you do it.